# How can I hook into new message windows using a bootstrapped Thunderbird extension?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, dom-events, xul, thunderbird-addon

I am currently trying to create a Thunderbird extension that write the recipients of a draft into the title of the composing window.
The default behaviour of Thunderbird is `Compose: [Subject]` (translated from German, YMMV), but I'd like to have something like this: `Compose to [recipient(s)]: [Subject]`, so my time tracking software can keep track of the time I spend writing emails to clients.

My general idea for this extension is:

1. Hook into every composing window that is created / opened (I know they are reused) via event listeners
2. For every `window`, listen to the event `recipients_changed`, if such a thing exists. Otherwise, it's a bit more work (monitor all recipient `input` fields), but that should not be a problem.
3. Also listen for `subject_changed` (easier, because it's only one `input`) to prevent the default title overwriting our extended title.

I have already created a skeleton extension (bootstrapped), and the `startup` function in `bootstrap.js` is actually getting called. Since this is my first extension to Firefox/Thunderbird, this is the first success! :)
However, the only reason I know the function is called because the many exceptions my different trials have thrown are logged in the error console...

I have read many texts, but the learning curve seems to be pretty steep.
I learned that at the time `startup` is called, pretty much nothing is defined yet (my first attempts were `alert` and then `settimeout`).

This answer looked promising, but it throws the exception `'wm' is not defined`:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14291575/1886765
Maybe I used the code wrongly - hard to say for a beginner.

It would probably be easier to make a non-bootstrapped extension (I could overlay the compose window and wouldn't need step #1), but now that I've started this way, I'd like to finish it this way.

Maybe the solution is some `XPCOM` connector, but this field is still completely dark for me.

Could you kindly point me in the right direction?

Comment: Did you make any more progress? I would recommend overlaying the compose window. I need to listen for `recipient_changed` events too, but I haven't found such a thing yet.

Comment: No, I am sorry, I have not.